# Using Auto and Lambda to handle Signal?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, signals, posix

I have written this program that has a main function, inside which, I am creating two sockets, like this:

```
int sockfd1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
int sockfd2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

Now I do some stuff with them, and when the user presses Ctrl+C to terminate the process, I want to make sure the sockets close properly, so I do this:

```
auto sigTermHandler = [&] (int param) { close(sockfd1); close(sockfd2); };
signal(SIGTERM, sigTermHandler);
```

But this throws the following compilation error when compiled as `g++ -std=gnu++0x <filename>.cpp`:

```
error: cannot convert ‘main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>’ to ‘__sighandler_t {aka void (*)(int)}’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void (* signal(int, __sighandler_t))(int)’
```

Is it not possible to use lambda this way to handle signals? Please advise.

P.S. I know I could put that in a destructor, if I did proper OOP, but I am curious to see if this works.

Comment: While this would certainly not help you, in case someone else in the future might need to use std::signal but are facing this issue, and can officially use Asio in the codebase, then Asio supports this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You cannot use the capture feature from lambda when calling a simple function pointer. The standard states that a lambda function without a capture is convertible to a function pointer, though:

> 5.1.2 (6) The closure type for a lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a public non-virtual non-explicit const
>   conversion function to pointer to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s
>   function call operator. The value returned by this conversion function shall be the address of a function
>   that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator.

For instance, this works:

```
signal(SIGTERM, [](int signum) { /* ... */ });
```

But not this:

```
signal(SIGTERM, [foo](int signum) { /* use foo here */ });
```

You could actually keep `sockfd1` and `sockfd2` as global variables and then, you could use them in the lambda function. But that is clearly not a good design. So it is better to use a [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) design. And if the program is terminated the sockets will be closed anyway (as @Dani is pointing out).

Answer (score 37):

A little late but if someone needs such a solution one can use `std::function` as a wrapper to hold a lambda capable of capturing variables:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

namespace {
std::function<void(int)> shutdown_handler;
void signal_handler(int signal) { shutdown_handler(signal); }
} // namespace

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
  MyTCPServer server;
  shutdown_handler = [&](int signal) {
    std::cout << "Server shutdown...\n";
    server.shutdown();
  };
  server.do_work_for_ever();
}
```

Comment: This will kill the program with an uncaught exception of type `bad_function_call` if a SIGINT happens (Ctrl+C) before the lambda is assigned to `shutdown_handler`.

Comment: @Bulletmagnet Yes you're right. It would be better to place if check before call like: `if (shutdown_handler)`

Comment: Or just assign shutdown_handler before the signal call?

Answer (score 0):

Sockets will always be closed when a program is closed, no need to worry about it.
If you worry about logical resource handling, put it in destructors, but those won't be called when the user presses CTRL-C

Comment: That's true, but they will not be closed immediately (up to a few seconds). If you run a program quickly twice in a row, for a socket bound to the specific port, you can get some error about the socket not able to bind.