# c++ capture ctrl+c without using globals

Tags: c++, c, lambda, function-pointers, sigint

I have simplified my example for an easier explanation. I am writing an application that counts to 100 but at any given time I allow the user to cancel the program by entering `ctrl+c` through the keyboard.

What seemingly started as a simple program quickly became complicated based on my lack of knowledge on function pointers. This is what I'm attempting to do:

1. Capture the SIGINT signal when `ctrl+c` is pressed.
2. Once captured, call a member function that shuts down a third-party resource.

The catch is that unlike the two examples that [Michael Haidl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48164204/5141619) and [Grijesh Chauhan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17766999/5141619) give on capturing `SIGINT`, I am not permitted to store any global variables. The ideal scenario is one in which all variables and function calls related to `signal()` are encapsulated within a class of mine.

Here's my modified attempt based on *Haidl* and *Grijesh's* code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>

class MyClass {
    public:
        volatile sig_atomic_t cancel = 0;
        void sig_handler(int signal) { 
            cancel = true; 
            this->libCancel();
        }   
        void libCancel() { std::cout << "Cancel and cleanup" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  MyClass mc; 
  //using std::placeholders::_1;
  //std::function<void(int)> handler = std::bind(&MyClass::sig_handler, mc, _1);
  //signal(SIGINT, handler);
  signal(SIGINT, &mc.sig_handler); // **compiler error** 

  for (int i = 0; !mc.cancel && i < 100; ++i)
  {
      std::cout << i << std::endl;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I'd like the code to simply count to 100 and exit if all goes well. But if the user calls `ctrl+c` then the class should handle `SIGINT`, call the external library for cleanup, and the `for` loop will exit.

**The main problem is that I can't seem to setup the `signal()` declaration to bind to my instance of `MyClass::sig_handler`. I even tried casting my member function to `std::function` to be used by `signal()`, commented out, but the compiler isn't happy about the fact that C++ `function<void(int)>` isn't equivalent to the C lang `void (*)(int)`.**

Any and all criticism is welcome. I'm not at all tied to what I've written and I clearly don't have a great fundamental understanding of how to use function pointers with member functions.

Comment: Signal handles are global. How do you expect it to function if there's more than one instance of `MyClass`?

Comment: good point, there is likely to only be one instance of `MyClass` does this mean I can simply have the `sig_handler` be static?

Comment: Yes, and have a global pointer pointing to the only instance of `MyClass` that you have. Which also raises the question why you need it to be a class in the first place.

Comment: You can't take the address of a non-static member function because you cannot call a non-static member function without some specific instance of the class. See pointer-to-member-function for more explanation (although you can't use a PTMF as a C callback either). You can use a static member function, although that is morally equivalent to a global variable.

Comment: Are you allowed to use static class variables? They have global lifetime, if not global scope.

Comment: the posted code is C++, not C (they are two different languages)  please remove the 'c' tag

Comment: If you are allowed to use Asio, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342305/using-boost-asio-to-catch-ctrl-c @Max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to communicate between the signal handler and the rest of the program using local variables. No parameters are passed into the handler other than the raised signal and the handler returns no value.

The words "global variables" are somewhat ambiguous. People sometimes mean different things depending on context. If your restriction applies only to the global scope, then simply use a `volatile sig_atomic_t` within some namespace. Or use static member variable, if you so prefer.

If your restriction applies to static storage duration, then you can use a thread local variable instead.

If your restriction applies to all global memory, then your problem is unsolvable using a signal handler. You simply need a global variable of some sort.

---

If you can rely on POSIX rather than C++ standard, A way to handle `SIGINT` without globals is to make sure that it is *not* handled, and block the thread with `sigwait`. If the call returns `SIGINT`, then stop the program, otherwise do what you want to do with the signal that was caught.

Of course, this means that the blocking thread doesn't do anything other than wait for signals. You'll need to do the actual work in other thread(s).

Technically though, global memory is probably still used. The use is simply hidden inside system library.

---

Furthermore, it is not safe to use `std::cout` within a signal handler. I know that is only an example, but *"call the external library for cleanup"* is very likely also async signal unsafe.

This can be fixed simply by calling the cleanup outside the for loop rather than inside the handler.

---

> The main problem is that I can't seem to setup the `signal()` declaration to bind to my instance of `MyClass::sig_handler`.

That's because `signal` requires a function pointer (of type `void(int)`). Non-static member functions cannot be pointed by function pointers. They can only be pointed by member function pointers, which `signal` doesn't accept.

Comment: Upvoted. Though I think `epoll` and `kqueue` let you pass context with the event.

Comment: I ended up using static member variables for class this did the trick